# extending an object stored in a database

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql

Is there a way to extend objects stored in a database?

example:

say I have an object:

```
{
id: 1
extends: null
type: HondaAccord
doors: 4
engine: 2 liter
dealerId: null
price: 20000
}
```

second object extends the first

```
{
id: 2
extends: 1
dealerId: 2
price: 25000
key1: value1
key2: value2
}
```

third Object ends the second:

```
{
id: 3
extends: 2
dealerId: 3
price: 27000
key1: some extended value
}
```

I want to be able to query the second object and get back:

```
{
id: 2
extends: 1
type: HondaAccord
doors: 4
engine: 2 liter
dealerId: 2
price: 25000
key1: value1
key2: value2
}
```

I want to be able to query the third object and get back:

```
{
id: 3
extends: 2
type: HondaAccord
doors: 4
engine: 2 liter
dealerId: 3
price: 27000
key1: some extended value
key2: value2
}
```

In a relational DB, I could normalize this data and do some complicated left joins etc to get this.

Is there a simpler way to do this in a NoSQL database?  My application requires that I be able to query these objects and get back the literal representation and also the expanded (as shown in the expected results) representation.

currently, I am doing this in Java code.  ie: fetch an object, see if it is supposed to extend another one, fetch that object and recurse through it.  If I needed to be able to grab a lot of "expanded" objects, there is a significant performance issue.

Any patterns to create something like this?  either SQL or NoSQL? seems almost like a decorator pattern but for data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$graphlookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) operation recursively matches on the "extends" and "id" attributes in the collection and returns the hierarchy for each queried document.

Apply [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) as the looked up data is not guaranteed to maintain order so we can resolve the duplicate keys in a orderly way.

Using current(3.4) prod version.

Use [`$arrayToObject`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23310) and [`$objectToArray`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18794) in a [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) with [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) to merge documents.

`$objectToArray` to produce array with key value pair for current (`$$this`) and `$$value` to concat all the key value pairs to produce an array of key value pairs followed by `$arrayToObject` to produce the merged document and [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) to promote as top level document.

`$sort` by "id" `desc` and "extend" `desc` to prefer the fields from the queried document over other lookup documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": collection,
      "startWith": "$id",
      "connectFromField": "extends",
      "connectToField": "id",
      "as": "hierarchy"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$hierarchy"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "id": -1,
      "hierarchy.extends": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "hierarchy": {
        "$push": "$hierarchy"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$reduce": {
            "input": "$hierarchy",
            "initialValue": [],
            "in": {
              "$concatArrays": [
                {
                  "$objectToArray": "$$this"
                },
                "$$value"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can use [`mergeObjects`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24879) aggregation operator is available in the current dev release 3.5.13  development release which will be rolled into upcoming 3.6 release.

`$sort` by "id" `desc` and "extend" `asc` to prefer the fields from the queried document over other lookup documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": collection,
      "startWith": "$id",
      "connectFromField": "extends",
      "connectToField": "id",
      "as": "hierarchy"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$hierarchy"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "id": -1,
      "hierarchy.extends": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "hierarchy": {
        "$push": "$hierarchy"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$hierarchy",
          "initialValue": {},
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```